# mgcv factor smooth interaction plot

Tags: mgcv

I am using mgcv with factor smooths to compare smooths of 5 Type factors. Example code is
 m <- gamm(Y ~ s(X,Type, bs="fs"),random=list(UnID=~1)
I plot the results using
plot(m)
but how do I link the different colours plotted to the factors. Essentially I need to produce a legend but cannot work out how to do this.

Comment: Hi Geoff! This is a programming question (hence closed as OT here). There isn't a way with the `plot()` method that **mgcv** provides. You can either take the data from the object returned by the `plot` method (i.e. in `foo` from `foo <- plot(m)`), or use my [**gratia** package](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia) and do `foo <- evaluate_smooth(m)` and then use **ggplot2** (there'll be a variable `Type` in `foo` that you can use for the colour aesthetic). You'll need to ask further Q's on [so] or in the Issues on the github site for **gratia** if something isn't clear or doesn't work.